# How to get no_of_products based on cus_id

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, join, lambda

I know this pretty simple. I'm new to entity framework and LINQ query. Anyway my question as follows

I have two tables,

Tbl_products

```
ID    No_of_Products     Lac_ID [FK]

001         5                 100
002         6                 300
003         2                 400
004         2                 200
```

Tbl_Cus_details

```
ID      CUS_ID

100     CUS001
200     CUS002
300     CUS003
400     CUS004
```

`Lac_ID` is foreign key of `Tbl_Cus_details`. I need to get `No_of_Products` based on  `CUS_ID`. how to write lambda expressions to get `No_of_Products` And I also need to know, lambda expressions and LINQ query both are same or different? what is the easy way to improve my knowledge of lambda expressions and LINQ query?

Comment: Show us what you've tried, and where you're having issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a join :

```
            DataTable products = new DataTable("Products");

            products.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
            products.Columns.Add("No_of_Products", typeof(int));
            products.Columns.Add("Lac_ID", typeof(string));

            products.Rows.Add(new object[] {"001", 5, "100"});
            products.Rows.Add(new object[] {"002", 6, "300"});
            products.Rows.Add(new object[] {"003", 2, "400"});
            products.Rows.Add(new object[] {"004", 2, "200"});


            DataTable details = new DataTable("Cus_details");
            details.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
            details.Columns.Add("CUS_ID", typeof(string));

            details.Rows.Add(new object[] {"100", "CUS001"});
            details.Rows.Add(new object[] {"200", "CUS002"});
            details.Rows.Add(new object[] {"300", "CUS003"});
            details.Rows.Add(new object[] {"400", "CUS004"});

            var results = (from p in products.AsEnumerable()
                           join d in details.AsEnumerable() on p.Field<string>("Lac_ID") equals d.Field<string>("ID")
                           select new { customer = d.Field<string>("CUS_ID"), number = p.Field<int>("No_of_Products") }).ToList();
```

Here is solution for one customer

---

```
            string customer = "CUS002";
            int product_count = details.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("CUS_ID") == customer).Select(x => x.Field<string>("ID"))
                .Select(x => products.AsEnumerable().Where(y => y.Field<string>("Lac_ID") == x).Sum(y => y.Field<int>("No_of_Products"))).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Sir, I need to pass `CUS_ID` as a parameter.  like , `select * from tblcustomer where cus_id = + "'" cID "'"`